# Enter your name as an ASCII hex string in the .DATA section of your program

Tags: assembly, x86, masm

So I dont understand how to do ASCII hex string in the .data section I am confused please help me understand.  I am suppose to put my name

```
.386
.model flat, stdcall
.stack 4096
 ExitProcess PROTO, dwExitCode: DWORD

.data
   str: .asciiz "637269737469616e2062656e6974657a"
.code

main PROC
  ; write your assembly code here
```

Answer (score 0):

Just enter the string naturally:

```
.data
   str: .asciiz "Cristian Benitez"
```

That's it.

`.asciiz` will produce a zero (NUL) -terminated ASCII string in the output binary.

See: http://web.mit.edu/gnu/doc/html/as_7.html#SEC71

What you've entered is an ASCII string. It just so happens that all of the characters are valid hex characters, and if you decode that hex string, it produces `cristian benitez`.

Comment: thank you for the feedback, but it tells me i am missing an operator in the expression

Comment: What assembler are you using? I was assuming GNU AS  but I see `ExitProcess`

Comment: I am using x 86 assembler

Comment: x86 is the target processor. There are many assemblers, e.g. MASM (Microsoft), GAS (GNU assembler), YASM, NASM, etc... They all have different syntactical quirks. If you don't know what assembler you're using, you should absolutely stop and figure that out first. If not, you're going to be helplessly trying likely invalid syntax.

Comment: I am using MASM I just figured it out

Comment: I was following an online tutorial on setting up a compiler for masm

Comment: For MASM, use `db` instead of `.asciiz`. Also put `,0` after the string for the terminator. For example: `str: db "prl",0`

Comment: If you want to do it in hex, put it without the quotes, and separate each byte with a comma: `str: db 63h,72h,69h,73h, ... , 7ah, 0`

Comment: @prl Please write an answer instead of answering in the comments. Since we now know the OP is using MASM, I intend to delete my invalid answer.